# node js SMTP error

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I am sending e mail through my godaddy email account. For that i am using node js for sending emails but it is giving following error :

```
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND] code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND', syscall: 'getaddrinfo' }
```

Source code:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'ssl://smtpout.secureserver.net',
    port: 465,
    auth: {
        user: 'Email address',
        pass: 'password'
    }
});

var mailOption = {
    from:  from,             
    to:   to ,                                   
    subject: subject,                            
    text:  body                                 
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOption,function(error, response){

    if(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    else{
        var successRes = { "status": "success" }
        res.send(successRes,200);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error is being shown because the host cannot be resolved i.e. because you are appending ssl:// to the host

As per the readme on [the github link for nodemailer-smtp-transport](https://github.com/andris9/nodemailer-smtp-transport) your createTransport should be something like this for a secure connection

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({ 
    host: 'smtpout.secureserver.net', 
    port: 465, 
    auth: { user: 'Email address', pass: 'password' },
    secure: true
});
```

Give  the above a shot, I think it should work just fine, if it is not working check your firewall/proxy setting.

Comment: No problem, I think you can mark the question as answered now.

Comment: the above code not work to me  Failed in sending mail
{ success: false, existing: false, sendError: true }
{ Error: Connection timeout

Comment: sorry now its working fine. The problem is proxy of my machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use ssl or secure socket layer in your host.Please remove the host and try.simply like

**host: 'smtpout.secureserver.net'**